# Implementing disabled button states with TailwindUI on NextJS app

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I have a NextJS app that was using Atomic CSS and has a button that is disabled if a form is not filled out:

```
      <Button
        className="primary"
        onClick={handleCreateCommunity}
        disabled={!phone || !communityName}
      >
        Create
      </Button>
```

I want to change to using my new TailwindUI primary buttons style:

```
.primary-btn {
    @apply inline-flex items-center px-6 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md shadow-sm text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500;
}
```

Obviously, I need to apply `className="primary"` --- but I don't know how to make the disabled state work.  Do I create another component that is like `.btn-disabled`?  But then how do I apply that style when the form is not filled out?

--

EDIT:

This is what my index.css looks like:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
    .primary-btn {
        @apply inline-flex items-center px-6 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md shadow-sm text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 disabled:bg-gray-300;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to make the tailwind css class work on top of atomic css or you want it to completely replace it with tailwind css?

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya - i want to completely replace it

Comment: I have added the desired solution . Hope it serves the purpose .

Answer (score 2):

You need to define styles for the [disabled state](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states) just like you do with `focus`.

Edit: You are not using [directives](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#layer) based on your comment. They are essential because they override default tailwind styles during compile, so they are not duplicated and they also purge unused custom styles at build.

Custom styles must be imported after the layer they are applied to. In your case after `@tailwind components`.

```css
@tailwind components;

@layer components {
 .primary-btn {
  @apply disabled:bg-blue-300;
 }
}
```

Comment: I got this `The 'disabled:bg-primary-300' class does not exist. If 'disabled:bg-primary-300' is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a '@layer' directive.`

Comment: I'm using 3.1.3

Comment: did you defined "primary" in tailwind config?

Comment: This error is coming for "primary", not for "disabled"

Comment: My example originally had `bg-primary-300` (I have it defined in mine) - I updated the answer to use a default tailwind color.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking an easy switch from `atomic-css` to `tailwind-css` i prefer you use `button` component provided by `tailwind-css`

Follow this rough pattern to get your desired result.

```
<button
  type="button"
  className=" /* enable class attributes */
               disabled: /* disabled class attributes*/ "
  disabled={/* disable logic in true or false */}
>
```

Hence your final code goes like :

```
<button
  type="button"
  className=" inline-flex items-center px-6 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md shadow-sm text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 disabled:bg-gray-300"
  onClick={handleCreateCommunity}
  disabled={!phone || !communityName} // your disable logic goes here
>
  Primary
</button>
```

Ouput :

When disabled is false :

[image]

When disabled is true

[image]

**Note:** if you want to define the class attributes in css file you can do that by adding style in index.css file in `@layer components`.

```
@layer components {
  .primary-btn {
    @apply m-5 inline-flex items-center px-6 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md shadow-sm text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 disabled:bg-gray-300;
  }
}
```

And then the className of Button becomes just `primary-btn`

```
 <button
      type="button"
      className="primary-btn"
      disabled={false} // your disable logic goes here
    >
      Primary
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this going to help you, but here is a simple approach. I am just using styles directly on my button and to render the disabled state I do this:

```
    <Button
    className="disabled:bg-gray-600 bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-700"
    onClick={handleCreateCommunity}
    disabled={!phone || !communityName}
  >
    Create
  </Button>
```